# ChromeDriver sometimes does and sometimes doesn't close

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to implement Selenium to scrape the pages from the list. While trying to scrape the list, sometimes, the execution just stops. It seems that sometimes the execution doesn't go past driver.close() and it happens completely at random. Below is the code I use to scrape multiple pages.

I would appreciate if anyone suggested a way to ensure that the driver closes after scraping the data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
addresses = ['address1', 'address2',...]
results = []
for address in addresses:
    driver = get_chromedriver() # returns webdriver instance
    driver.get(f"https://www.example.com/{address}")
    values = scrape_some_data()

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
    results.append(values)
 # do something with the list of values
```

Comment: just checking, but more or less randomly, the program reaches driver.close and just doesnt go further? No errors or anything? Also I assume the indentation is just incorrect for this snippet due to formating, right?

Comment: `driver.close()`,  `driver.quit()` - they both have different purposes. can you simply just put  `driver.quit()` and see the behavior if it works consistently. and make sure to have a latest version of chromedriver

Comment: @Zaid Al Shattle thanks, the indetation was incorrect - while simplifying the code in order to post it here, I made an error - now I corrected it. Correct - there are no errors, the code just stops executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I have noticed which might, or might not, be helpful in solving your issues:

1. Unless you really need to, it might be better to call `driver = get_chromedriver()` outside the loop, and run the `driver.quit()` after the loop is complete, that will speed up your execution significantly as your browser will not need to re-open. However if you are accessing multiple instances of the same website then you might need to depend on your method.
2. `driver.quit()` should be sufficient for your use without the need for `driver.close()` here.
3. If you want to use multiple instances definitely, it might be better to use threading. I've heard of a few cases where issues can occur if a loop is used while destroying/recreating the driver over and over.

Comment: Thanks! I modified the logic such that every driver runs in its own thread. It turned out that for some instances it takes very long time to close (don't know why). The data that has to be scraped is retrieved and hence in case of having multiple threads it doesn't matter that much if some threads are terminated later.

Comment: Yea, selenium can act quite inconsistently sometimes from personal experience. More or when closing/reopening.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code as below.
You declare webdriver instance once and use `driver.get` to open a browser url.

Also, I suggest to append all values before you quit webdriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = get_chromedriver() # returns webdriver instance
addresses = ['address1', 'address2',...]
results = []
for address in addresses:
    driver.get(f"https://www.example.com/{address}")
    values = scrape_some_data()
    results.append(values)
    driver.close()

# do something with the list of values
```

Difference between driver.close() and driver.quit():

- close() method closes the current window.
- quit() method quits the driver and closes every associated window.

So, if you want one window to be closed, use `close()`, all windows - `quit()`

One more thing I suggest: add explicit waits for all your data to be loaded before webdriver is closed.
To use explicit waits import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And use like:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css_selector")))  # for a list of elements
```

Take this as an example: [How to find and compare text with the style property using Selenium/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68307733/how-to-find-and-compare-text-with-the-style-property-using-selenium-python/68308199#68308199)

If all above suggestions will not work, try closing webdriver in `finally` block.